# Navbar Toggle button is not working and it's only showing the toggle icon but not working when clicked upon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid main_menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-12 mx-auto">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button
                class="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"
                      >Home</a
                    >
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link disabled"
                      href="#"
                      tabindex="-1"
                      aria-disabled="true"
                      >Disabled</a
                    >
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried other tips but none of them seem to be working and the toggle button won't work.
The navbar is copied from the original bootstrap website but still, it won't work, please guide me.
Thanks in advance for giving your efforts.
You are amazing!
No need to read from now on because I am only adding some text so that I can post because while posting I am getting an issue that reads "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.". So yeah, here we go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following format:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid main_menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-12 mx-auto">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button
                 class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >

                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"
                      >Home</a
                    >
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link disabled"
                      href="#"
                      tabindex="-1"
                      aria-disabled="true"
                      >Disabled</a
                    >
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked! 
Can you please tell me what are the changes you made.

Comment: @Andy-404, data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" // <== this is your toggle button attributes ('data-bs-toggle' and 'data-bs-target' is used for bootstrap 5). 

data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" // <== this is mine toggle button attributes ('data-toggle' and 'data-target' is used for bootstrap 4.6).
for more details, please check this (getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar). 

Note: Another thing is that, in your code, you didn't use the jquery library in your code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of your question
i replaced the bootstrap links with the official bootstrap link from there website and this started working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid main_menu">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-12 mx-auto">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                        aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

css link

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

js bundle link

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

for more info check
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

```
                             <!DOCTYPE html>
                             <html lang="en">
                             
                             <head>
                                 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                                 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                                 <!--Boostrap Stylesheet-->
                             
                                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
                             
                             
                                 <!--Boostrap Scripts-->
                             
                                 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                                 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                                 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                             
                             
                                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
                                 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
                             
                                 <title>Document</title>
                             </head>
                             
                             <body>
                                 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                                     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                                                                                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                                                                                              </button>
                             
                                     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                             <li class="nav-item active">
                                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                             </li>
                                             <li class="nav-item">
                                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                                             </li>
                                             <li class="nav-item">
                                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                                             </li>
                                             <li class="nav-item">
                                                 <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                                             </li>
                                         </ul>
                                     </div>
                                 </nav>
                             </body>
                             
                             </html>
```